# Trouble with downloading python packages. It says Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, stable-diffusion

Some stable diffusion extensions require the use of specific Python packages. In my case, I need to download open cv package. But everytime I try to download it, it shows: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"D:\Python\python.exe"  "D:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe" install opencv-python ': The system cannot find the file specified
[image]
What do I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, make sure you have already installed pip in your device.

```
 pip -V

It should display your current pip version...
```

2. You don't need to go to "D" Drive to run pip
3. If it is not working, you can make it by local installation.
   Download your required package from https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#files (It will be .whl format). Place in a local folder and execute the following command.

```
 pip install "your local folder path"
```